# How to know status in AWS Lambda code that Redshift table loaded successfully

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift

I have requirement to load data from one Redshift cluster to another, each in different region.

For same first creating table in target schema and then on source running `UNLOAD` command, which will put files in an S3 bucket.

To load data from S3 to target Redshift schema, I will use python code in AWS Lambda. The AWS Lambda function will trigger on the S3 path where all files will come when the unload command is executed.

After ingestion I need to run a transformation query that will put data in fact and dimension tables. How can I know the status for target table that a particular table loaded successfully?

The Lambda python code will triggered for each file, and will copy data to the target table. If I know the status I will issue the transformation query.

Is there any feature in AWS Lambda that will help me to know the status of the `COPY` command?

Comment: How long does it take to load the data via `COPY`? If it takes a long time then AWS Lambda is not a good way to load it.

Comment: As in unload command we have parallel on, and each file size not more then 400 MB & to load 400 MB file it will take less then 15 minutes, so we are good to go.

Comment: Can't you just wait for the `COPY` to finish and then send the transformation commands? That is, whatever library you are using to issue the `COPY` command will probably return when the command is finished, so send the next command after that.

Comment: for ex. table A has total 96 files, and unload command will unloading data in parallel. so trigger also happen in parallel and its difficult for me to know which one completed first and last.

Comment: So the flow is `TABLE -> UNLOAD -> S3 -> LAMBDA -> COPY -> Transform`? If so, why are you unloading the data at all, if it is just to load in again? By the way, you can use `UNLOAD ... PARALLEL OFF` to create a single output file in S3.